# Array_multisort can't find my associative key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort the keys of my array depending on an element sequence I created.

Here is an example of my array:

```
[
 {
 -14297: [
     -{
         waypoint_id: "14297"
         sequence: 27
         order_id: 12271
      }
    ]
 -34502: [
     -{
         waypoint_id: "34502"
         sequence: 19
         order_id: 30484

      },
     -{
         waypoint_id: "345202"
         sequence: 19
         order_id: 433

      }
  ]
```

So far i've tried to do this:

```
    $sort = array();
    foreach($myArr as $k=>$v) {
        $sort['sequence'][$k] = $v['sequence'];

    }
    array_multisort($sort['sequence'], SORT_ASC, $myArr );
```

But I keep getting an error that 'sequence' is not defined.

MY expected output is as follows:

```
[
 -34502: [
     -{
         waypoint_id: "34502"
         sequence: 19
         order_id: 30484

      },
     -{
         waypoint_id: "345202"
         sequence: 19
         order_id: 433

      }

  -14297: [
     -{
         waypoint_id: "14297"
         sequence: 27
         order_id: 12271
      }
    ]

  ]
```

Note: This is a json object. I'm returning $myArr;

print_r gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [36862] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [waypoint_id] => 36862
                    [sequence] => 1
                    [order_id] => 32628

                )

        )

    [35633] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [waypoint_id] => 35633
                    [sequence] => 2
                    [order_id] => 31452

                ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [waypoint_id] => 35633
                    [sequence] => 2
                    [order_id] => 34343

                )

        )
```

Which gives me the correct return..

Comment: What output is your expecting? Please post your final expected output.

Comment: Can you do `print_r($myArr);` and show us the output of that?

Comment: Is that json Object?

Comment: @nbin Yes, it's a json object.

Comment: have u converted it to php array?

Comment: @Jerodev I did the print_r and it gave me the correct sequence...but when I `return $myArr;` it's all off

Comment: @nbin I return it as a json object so that I can play around with it on client side.

Comment: is your error in foreach loop or in multi_sort?

Comment: @nbin yes it's inside the foreach loop

Comment: The problem is the structure of your array. While the first dimension of your array can have n further arrays $v can have a number of children or an array with the keys you expect. Maybe you should change the structure of your array.

Answer (score 0):

So if you can give your array a structure, that is comparable the following example should work out pretty well for you.

Unsortet Array

```
$array = new ArrayIterator([
    [
        'element_id' => 34502,
        'waypoint_id' => 34502,
        'sequence' => 19,
        'order_id' => 30484
    ],
    [
        'element_id' => 34502,
        'waypoint_id' => 345202,
        'sequence' => 19,
        'order_id' => 433
    ],
    [
        'element_id' => 14297,
        'waypoint_id' => 14297,
        'sequence' => 27,
        'order_id' => 12271
    ]
]);
```

With the SplMinHeap class of PHP 's own SPL library you can sort your array by sequence

```
class SequenceMinHeap extends SplMinHeap {
    public function compare($sequence1, $sequence2) {
        return $sequence2['sequence'] - $sequence1['sequence'];
    }
}

$result = new SequenceMinHeap();
while ($array->valid()) {
    $result->insert($array->current());
    $array->next();
}
```

Keep in mind, that this is an approach that works fine with a well structured array. If you can not organize your array you should try to get this approach work recursive on your original array. This results in a hell of work. So perhaps using SplHeap with a well organized array is the better solution.